# Javascript element height weirdness

Tags: javascript, layout, console, height

When I console log the innerHeight/clientHeight/offsetHeight of my element in my console (firefox) it says a TOTALLY different number than when I access it:
[image: The two console logs (the bottom is the accessed height)]

[image: The clientHeight in the div]

[image: The two console logs in the code]

This seems like complete madness to me. I have already tried using jquery with height() too.

Please enlighten me! Much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the value of your box-sizing property? [Box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: When console logging it's empty, so I'd say null.

Comment: Please post your code, not screenshots of output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the default value is content-box. Try setting it to border-box in your css file and check again. "box-sizing: border-box"

Comment: Changes the number, but still nowhere close

Comment: post your code here. Without it, no one can help you

Comment: I posted the code that is needed.. I use vue, better yet, vuejs that creates the elements, so posting more code wont help. The question is, why does a value in my console log not equal to the same value when I access it? On the exact same variable? In the exact same scope, method call, everything, it's just nuts.